# Expression Blend: Insert a row into a grid at design time

Tags: expression-blend

Ok, so I have a grid with lots of controls. And oops, I missed something and need to move everything down one row...

type type type

My mistake, I needed two rows...

type type type

Ok, this really sucks. So, how do I insert a row in a way that will move everything down.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure which version of Blend you are on, but in version 4 I can click to the left of the grid to divide a row into two.  This has three effects:

1. creates a new row in the Grid.RowDefinitions section
2. adds 1 to the Grid.Row attributes of all rows beneath your division (moves them all down a row)
3. adds 1 to the Grid.RowSpan attribute of all controls in the row you have divided

You can now manually change the the RowSpans back to their original value and voila - you have a blank row.